# Python: Ensure that Threads aren't Running in the Background

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm going through an example from a book about threading, and this is the example they give:

```
## To use threads you need import Thread using the following code:
from threading import Thread

##Also we use the sleep function to make the thread "sleep" 
from time import sleep

## To create a thread in Python you'll want to make your class work as a thread.
## For this, you should subclass your class from the Thread class
class CookBook(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = "Hello Parallel Python CookBook!!\n"

##this method thod prints only the message 
    def print_message(self):
        print (self.message)

##The run method prints ten times the message 
    def run(self):
        print ("Thread Starting\n")
        x=0
        while (x < 10):
            self.print_message()
            sleep(2)
            x += 1
        print ("Thread Ended\n")


#start the main process
print ("Process Started")

# create an instance of the HelloWorld class
hello_Python = CookBook()

# print the message...starting the thread
hello_Python.start()

#end the main process
print ("Process Ended")

#create an instance of the HelloWorld class
hello_Python = CookBook()

#print the message...starting the thread
hello_Python.start()

#end the main process
print ("Process Ended")
```

It's the first example in the first chapter, and at the end of the chapter the author says to make sure that you don't have any threads running in the background, that it's bad programming.

**Question:**

Given my example, how do you properly **verify** no threads are running in the background?

Comment: @user590028 - It runs the way the book says it would. This is interesting. Hm.

Comment: The think the author's comment was general advice -- meaning that if you combined his example with other code, it was up to you to make sure you did not have other threads running, which could interfere with the expected output.

Comment: @user590028 - Sorry for the late reply, but thanks. Just for my own understanding, how would you verify no other threads were running? the best practice.

Comment: That you didn't run them.  Python is always running with multiple threads, so any attempt to count threads will always return more than one. The author was advising you to not create additional threads or you could confuse the example he was trying to make.

Comment: @user590028 - In my particular case, and I think I might be getting confused, how would I verify that when I call hello_world.start() that the thread actually finishes, and isn't still running in the background? the hello_world thread specifically.

Comment: Ahh -- join the thread, https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Comment: @user590028 - That's what I was thinking! But I wasn't sure. Thanks, so just to clarify I would say hello_world.join(), correct?

Comment: I should point out two things; first you could read the docs & try it for yourself. Second, StackOverflow requires a minimum answer -- so I could not just say yes -- which forces me to write a long message.

Comment: @user590028 - Can't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways depending on what you need:

1. Use `join()`, as comment suggested.
2. Set your thread daemon thread, which means calling `Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)`. When your main thread exits, other threads you create automatically exit too, thus you don't have to worry about them running in background.